# Error that is thrown

Tags: java

I'm passing through a java test and the following issue has come up:

Why is the following claim wrong?

> An Error that might be thrown in a method must be declared as thrown
>   by that method, or be handled within that method.

I couldn't get an example of such an ill-formed program. I really have no idea.

Comment: `Error` and its subclasses are [unchecked exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html). You don't have to explicitly declare them as thrown or catch them. They're supposed to represent non-recoverable conditions (caused by programming errors) so catching them does not really make sense. Let alone tasking the users of an API with handling them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an Error (as opposed to an Exception) is not a checked exception, and therefore doesn't have to be handled by the method or declared as thrown.

In fact, an `Error` usually shouldn't be caught, as mentioned in the Javadoc :

> An *Error* is a subclass of *Throwable* that indicates serious problems that **a reasonable application should not try to catch.**

It also says:

> A method **is not required to declare in its *throws*
>   clause any subclasses of *Error* that might be thrown 
>   during the execution of the method but not caught**, since these 
>   errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur.